# SQL Server Windows authentication using other people's credential

Tags: python, sql-server, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database (where only Windows authentication is allowed) via Python. the Python part serves as a web API and the permission control is under AD group on the SQL server. Thus, instead of using my own identity, I need to use other's ones (provided their Windows username and password)

Assuming I'm user A and I try to log in to the server on behalf of user B. (Of course I know his Windows login). Firstly I'm using Python-ldap to get the authencation.

```
# This step runs successfully
conn_ladp = ldap.initialize("ldap://ladp_address:389")
login_str = 'userB@domain.com'
password = 'userB_pw'
handle = conn_ladp.simple_bind_s(login_str ,password)
```

Then I try to connect to the server

```
conn_sql = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=server_name;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn_sql.cursor()
# I checked the permision, it's still using user A's identity.
cursor.execute('some query')
```

However it's still under my current identity (user A). Seems that there is some 'miscommunication' between the ldap and pyodbc. Could anyone help me figure out how to connect them and fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Either you missed showing us some code or you're trying to connect with pyodbc without passing the credentials that you just setup.

Comment: @jhomr  Thanks for responding, I don't think Imiss any code. So I might just need to know how to 'passing the credentials that I just setup towards pyodbc', setting trusted_connection flag isn't enough?

Comment: Doesn't seem so. If you are trying to log in as a different user, there are flags for UID and password for PYODBC connection string. Probably need to check that out and re-evaluate what you have so far :)

Comment: @jhomr That's not gonna work. The server does not allowed to login through UID & PW, only Windows authentication.

Comment: I don't believe PYODBC supports that directly. As far as I know, you would have to impersonate that user and probably pass the connection *while impersonating that user*

Comment: @jhomr Could you please give some instruction on this?